# Get-PAMGroup - ObjectSID Null

Tags: powershell, identity-management

Good day

I'm using the PAM (Privileged Access Management) service and i'm getting this error when I try to run Get-PAMGroup Cmdlet

`Get-PamGroup`

```
Get-PAMGroup : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ObjectSID
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PAMGroup
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-PAMGroup], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.IdentityManagement.AdminPamCmdlets.GetPamGroupCommand
```

I don't know why this is happening, because I have the Contoso.[groups] created in the Contoso AD

Users and groups were created following the MS Docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/pam/step-6-transition-group-to-pam

NOTE: I'm sorry about the TAGS, I don't have enough reputation to create Privileged-Access-Management Tag

Thanks